# Inverse round corners with Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, bezier-curve, button, corners

I am trying to reproduce these buttons:

[image: example buttons]

Here is my attempt, but I don't know how to inverse the round corner to match the reference images:

[image: wrong pointing rounded corners]

Any idea is welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Bézier tool <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> to draw a closed path as in the example shown below

You can hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> as you use the tool to constrain the angles at the corners to 45 degrees, and for right angles at 90 degrees.

Then use the Edit Paths by Nodes tool <kbd>F2</kbd> to curve the corner segments.

[image]